# MIPS architecture: what happens if r1 is not equal to r3 when executing something like beq r1,r3,00?

Tags: mips

Which instruction will come into the pipeline and what would result with those instructions already fetched and in the pipeline?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor says "The early implementations of SPARC and MIPS (two of the first commercial RISC architectures) used single-direction static branch prediction: they always predict that a conditional jump will not be taken, so they always fetch the next sequential instruction." so the pipeline is altered only when the operands are equal.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://github.com/valar1234/MIPS

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the implementation of the processor.

Some processors would have predicted that the branch will fall through rather than being taken.  In the case of your question, such a processor that correctly predicted, will incur no penalty.

The complexities of the prediction mechanism and the time to determine a successful/failed prediction vary greatly.  In the case of an incorrect prediction one or more cycles are may be lost, but again that depends on the implementation, and there have been lots of them over the years for MIPS.

Over the years, prediction has improved from simple prediction (all branches: predict not taken), to using dynamic history-based prediction.  At some evolution, in doing dynamic prediction, the stage that actually makes the prediction has also moved backward in the pipeline.  Further, the pipeline stage that ultimately decides the actual branch/not decision has also moved backward in the pipeline.  These improvements limit the number of mispredicts, as well as wasted cycles on a mispredict.

Instructions fetched (so execution begun) but on a mispredicted code path are simply not committed, wasting a cycle, which some call a bubble.